filling a php form always ends up on a blank page, never adds information into the database
I am trying to insert data submitted in a form, into a MySQL Database, and I can't see the problem in my code. Each time i try to insert it it ends up on a white page and the database remains empty.
this is the html form
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Registro para el sorteo</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Registro para el sorteo</h1>
    <form action="register.php" method="post">
        <label for="email">Email:</label>
        <input type="email" id="email" name="email" required><br><br>

        <label for="nombre">Nombre:</label>
        <input type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre" maxlength="20" required><br><br>

        <label for="apellidos">Apellidos:</label>
        <input type="text" id="apellidos" name="apellidos" maxlength="30" required><br><br>

        <label for="fecha_nacimiento">Fecha de nacimiento:</label>
        <input type="date" id="fecha_nacimiento" name="fecha_nacimiento" required><br><br>

        <label for="telefono">Teléfono:</label>
        <input type="text" id="telefono" name="telefono" maxlength="9" required pattern="\d{9}"><br><br>

        <label for="color_preferido">Color preferido:</label>
        <input type="color" id="color_preferido" name="color_preferido" required><br><br>

        <label for="numero">Número para el sorteo (0-999):</label>
        <input type="number" id="numero" name="numero" min="0" max="999" required><br><br>

        <input type="submit" value="Registrar">
    </form>
</body>
</html>


And this the php part of the registration
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root"; 
$dbname = "sorteo";


$conn = new mysqli($localhost, $root, $root, $sorteo);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
}


$email = $_POST['email'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
$fecha_nacimiento = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];
$telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
$color_preferido = $_POST['color_preferido'];
$numero = $_POST['numero'];

$fecha_actual = new DateTime();
$fecha_nacimiento_dt = new DateTime($fecha_nacimiento);
$edad = $fecha_actual->diff($fecha_nacimiento_dt)->y;

if ($edad < 18) {
    die("Debes ser mayor de edad para participar en el sorteo.");
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO participantes (email, nombre, apellidos, fecha_nacimiento, telefono, color_preferido, numero) 
        VALUES ('$email', '$nombre', '$apellidos', '$fecha_nacimiento', '$telefono', '$color_preferido', '$numero')";

if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Registro exitoso. <a href='participants.php'>Ver participantes</a>";
} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}

$conn->close();

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

This a list to delete, update or obtain the list of participants
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = ""; 
$dbname = "sorteo";


$conn = new mysqli($localhost, $root, $root, $sorteo);


if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Conexión fallida: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {

        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $sql = "DELETE FROM participantes WHERE email='$email'";
        $conn->query($sql);
    } elseif (isset($_POST['update'])) {
      
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
        $apellidos = $_POST['apellidos'];
        $fecha_nacimiento = $_POST['fecha_nacimiento'];
        $telefono = $_POST['telefono'];
        $color_preferido = $_POST['color_preferido'];
        $sql = "UPDATE participantes SET nombre='$nombre', apellidos='$apellidos', fecha_nacimiento='$fecha_nacimiento', telefono='$telefono', color_preferido='$color_preferido' WHERE email='$email'";
        $conn->query($sql);
    }
}


$sql = "SELECT * FROM participantes";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Lista de Participantes</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Lista de Participantes</h1>
    <table border="1">
        <tr>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Nombre</th>
            <th>Apellidos</th>
            <th>Fecha de Nacimiento</th>
            <th>Teléfono</th>
            <th>Color Preferido</th>
            <th>Número</th>
            <th>Acciones</th>
        </tr>
        <?php
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<form method='post' action='participants.php'>";
                echo "<td><input type='hidden' name='email' value='" . $row['email'] . "'>" . $row['email'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' name='nombre' value='" . $row['nombre'] . "'></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' name='apellidos' value='" . $row['apellidos'] . "'></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='date' name='fecha_nacimiento' value='" . $row['fecha_nacimiento'] . "'></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='text' name='telefono' value='" . $row['telefono'] . "'></td>";
                echo "<td><input type='color' name='color_preferido' value='" . $row['color_preferido'] . "'></td>";
                echo "<td>" . $row['numero'] . "</td>";
                echo "<td><button type='submit' name='update'>Actualizar</button> <button type='submit' name='delete'>Eliminar</button></td>";
                echo "</form>";
                echo "</tr>";
            }
        } else {
            echo "<tr><td colspan='8'>No hay participantes registrados.</td></tr>";
        }
        ?>
    </table>
</body>
</html>

<?php
$conn->close();

ini_set('display_errors', '1');
ini_set('display_startup_errors', '1');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
?>

And the sql code
CREATE DATABASE sorteo;
USE sorteo;

CREATE TABLE participantes (
    email VARCHAR(50) PRIMARY KEY,
    nombre VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    apellidos VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
    fecha_nacimiento DATE NOT NULL,
    telefono VARCHAR(9) NOT NULL,
    color_preferido VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL,
    numero INT NOT NULL
);


As i said i tried to make it so when the form is filled the data adds to the database on mysql

You switch on showing error messages at the bottom of your PHP scripts. That's rather useless. If you do it at the top of the script it might report something, unless you have a syntax error. For those you need to look in the error logs.

If you care about the security of your database see: SQL Injection.

In your second PHP script you have a syntax error: On line 31 there's one to many }. Inconsistent indentation probably caused this error.

I'm not sure where you've been learning from, but this is totally the wrong way to build a SQL query using PHP when you're incorporating user input into it. 1) It's vulnerable to SQL injection attacks, and 2) it can be crashed with simple syntax issues due to the input values  - e.g. anyone with a ' in their name (such as O'Reilly)  would crash your query because SQL would think the ' was terminating the input string after the O.

Instead you must use prepared statements and parameters to correctly build the query and insert the values safely. See How to include a PHP variable inside a MySQL statement, How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP? and https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli for some excellent resources and simple examples of how to do this stuff properly. Even as a beginner on a practice project you should get into good habits.

Never configure your web app to login to the database as root. Root can do whatever it likes, so on top of the SQL injection vulnerabilities this just leaves your database an open book for hackers. Instead create a separate user account specifically for this application which has only the permissions it actually needs in order to work properly. Don't even use the root account as a shortcut during development or testing, because you need to test your account permissions as well - otherwise when you go live you might have unexpected errors relating to the user account setup.

And please bring your SQL error handling into the 21st century. Add mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); before your mysqli_connect() (or new mysqli()) command, and this will ensure that errors with your SQL queries are reported correctly to PHP automatically. That way you don't need to clutter your script with repetitive code to keep checking errors after every mysqli command. And you should never be echoing error data deliberately - it can easily reveal sensitive info to attackers by accident. In a live environment you should always log all PHP errors to a file.

I'm guessing you've been following some really old, out-of-date and poor-quality tutorial, which has unfortunately led to all these fundamental problems in your code.

And read https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting to learn how to set up your general error handling sensibly

Thanks everyone for the comments, i REALLY need to check this code out and update it, i appreciate all the tips and links to better guides!
